# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL

Tags: java, android, opengles

Всем привет, у меня возникла ошибка вот в этом куске кода :

```
GLES30.glGenVertexArrays(1, vao, 0);

GLES30.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

int[] vbo = new int[1];
int[] vbo_indices = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vbo, 0);
GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, vbo_indices, 0);

FloatBuffer posBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions.length);
posBuffer.put(positions);
posBuffer.position(0);

GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.length * 4, posBuffer, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

IntBuffer indicesBuf = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
indicesBuf.put(indices);
indicesBuf.position(0);

GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_indices[0]);
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuf.capacity() * 4, indicesBuf, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GLES30.glBindBuffer(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

zGLES30.glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Если точнее, то в :

```
GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuf.capacity() * 4, indicesBuf, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);GLES30.glBufferData(GLES30.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuf.capacity() * 4, indicesBuf, GLES30.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Вот сама ошибка :

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: jarray was NULL
in call to GetPrimitiveArrayCritical
from void android.opengl.GLES20.glBufferData(int, int, java.nio.Buffer, int)
```

Вот еще функция `crateIntBuffer`:

```
public static IntBuffer createIntBuffer(int numInts) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(numInts * 4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    return buffer.asIntBuffer();
}
```

Прошу тех кто знает в чем проблема помочь, заранее спасибою.

Answer (score 4):

Используйте `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...)` в `BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(positions.length);`

Проблема в том, что `glBufferData` требует direct-буфер, который можно эффективно использовать совместно с нативным кодом. Если же используется `ByteBuffer.allocate(...)` или что-то вроде `FloatBuffer.wrap(...)`, то это не будет direct-буфером. Поэтому надо использовать `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...)` для выделения буфера и `ByteBuffer.put(...)` для его инициализации.

Comment: Можете написать более развернутый ответ?

Comment: Sorry not in Russian, I was having the same issue and found this question in search. The problem is that glBufferData requires a direct buffer that can be shared efficiently with native code. If you're using `ByteBuffer.allocate(...)` or something like `FloatBuffer.wrap(...)` it won't be a direct buffer. So you can use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...)` and `ByteBuffer.put(...)` to initialize the Buffer.

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineLaFayette, may be you can translate your comment with google-translate and edit answer with it? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я перевёл, но не знаю, как по-русски называется direct-буфер.

Comment: @Qwertiy так и называется большинством. Хотя, я видел тех, кто называл его прямым буфером :)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, отлично! Я ожидал что-то в духе "нативный", "непосредственный", "чистый", прямым бы как-то и не подумал назвать.